# Rails 4 ActiveRecord scope to query different date field based on whether it exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, active-record-query

I have a VoyageLeg model that has many date fields. I have an instance method as below to get one of the dates based on whether it has been populated:

```
def calc_arrival_date
  if ada
    ada #return actual date of arrival
  elsif updated_eda
    updated_eda #return updated estimated date of arrival
  else
    eda #return estimated date of arrival
  end
end
```

I also have a Voyage model that has_many voyage_legs. How would I create a scope on the Voyage model would would reference the `calc_arrival_date`, or alternatively do the same logic regarding which date to query in the scope?

I.e. I would like to be able to have a scope on the Voyage that would do something like:

```
scope :archived, -> { joins(:voyage_legs).where("voyage_legs.calc_arrival_date < ?", Time.zone.now) }
```

Comment: you meant to pass the date as a param in scope?

Comment: No I don't think so. I want to query the field `ada` if it is not nil, otherwise `updated_ada` if it is not nil, otherwise `eda` and then if it is in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using part of your code @Shabini Rajadas, but combined the date clause inside the logic as a class method on the VoyageLeg model as follows:

```
def self.departed
  where("CASE WHEN voyage_legs.add IS NOT NULL THEN
      voyage_legs.add < :now
    WHEN voyage_legs.updated_edd IS NOT NULL THEN
      voyage_legs.updated_edd < :now
    WHEN voyage_legs.add IS NULL and voyage_legs.updated_edd IS NULL THEN
      voyage_legs.edd  < :now END", now: Time.zone.now.to_date)
end
```

Then I can filter Voyages like `Voyage.joins(:voyage_legs).merge(VoyageLeg.departed)`

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your request, a little more extra work to be done.

The scope method,

```
scope :archived, -> {joins(:voyage_legs).select('(CASE WHEN voyage_legs.ada IS NOT NULL THEN voyage_legs.ada WHEN voyage_legs.updated_eda IS NOT NULL THEN voyage_legs.updated_eda WHEN voyage_legs.ada IS NULL and voyage_legs.updated_eda IS NULL THEN voyage_legs.eda END) as calc_arrival_date')}
```

And a little calculations on the result,

```
result = Voyage.archived.select { |b| b.calc_arrival_date.to_datetime < Time.zone.now  }
```

Comment: I don't think the scope is working, I get the error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'calc_arrival_date' for #<Voyage:0x000000068ceaa0>` when I run the second statement. If i do `Voyage.archived.to_sql` I get `"SELECT \"voyages\".* FROM \"voyages\" INNER JOIN \"voyage_legs\" ON \"voyage_legs\".\"voyage_id\" = \"voyages\".\"id\" AND \"voyage_legs\".\"deleted_at\" IS NULL WHERE \"voyages\".\"deleted_at\" IS NULL AND (voyage_legs.ada < '2016-10-25 19:19:53.640705')" ` so it isn't doing the SQL in the select.